# How to map an object stream to a specific type

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `JSONArray` of objects, and I want to map each object to a `JSONObject`.

I tried:

```
JSONArray array; //my json array
array.stream().map(obj -> (JSONObject) obj).forEach((JSONObject prof) -> {
    //code
});
```

However the type is already encapsulated by `Object` and thus I cannot seem to cast it down. How can I achieve this with Java 8 streams?

Comment: Which library does this `JSONArray` come from?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis json-simple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few issues here. `JSONArray` is a raw sub type of `ArrayList`. Therefore the methods it inherits are also raw, all their type parameter uses are erased and reduce to `Object`. Just that should tell you that things will not be safe going forward.

The invocation of

```
array.stream().map(..)
```

is raw. Therefore the `Function` that `map` accepts will also be raw. The returned `Stream` will also be raw. And therefore the `forEach` invoked will operate on `Object`, the resulting type from erasure. There's nothing you can do about this except for casting in between operations. Something like

```
Stream stream = array.stream().map(obj -> (JSONObject) obj);
((Stream<JSONObject>) stream).forEach((JSONObject prof) -> {
    // code
});
```

But this is in no way safe (unless you know there are only `JSONObject` objects in the `JSONArray`). Which brings us to...

> I have a JSONArray of objects, and I want to map each object to a JSONObject.

You have to decide how to do this mapping. `JSONArray` can contain `JSONObject`, Strings, numbers, etc. Simply casting to a `JSONObject` won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Your code won't work, since the `ArrayList` that is the base type of `JSONArray` has no type parameter specified. You can simply "add" one by casting:

```
((List<?>)array).stream().map(obj -> (JSONObject) obj).forEach((JSONObject prof) -> {
    //code
});
```

But in your code example I really don't see any reason not to use only one lambda expression like this:

```
array.stream().forEach(obj -> {
    JSONObject prof = (JSONObject) obj;
    //code
});
```